# Correlation matrix in Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am doing Spotify data analysis. I would like to create a correlation matrix using Plotly. My sample data frame as below (dataframe name called 'df')

[image]

I created a correlation matrix by using below code

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


trace = go.Heatmap(z=df.values,x=df.index.values,y=df.columns.values,colorscale='RdBu_r',
                   zmax=1,zmin=-1,text=corr.values)
fig = go.Figure(data=[trace])
pyo.plot(fig)
fig.show()
```

Getting below output

[image]

I need to get a clear correlation matrix output, can anyone advise how to do this in Plotly? Unable to fix the above code in order to get the right output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think we can use `df.corr()` in pandas to calculate the correlation coefficient and make a heatmap of it.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'danceability': np.random.rand(100),
                  'energy': np.random.rand(100),
                  'loudness': np.random.rand(100),
                  'mode': random.choices([0,1], k=100)})
df_corr = df.corr()

print(df_corr)
danceability    energy  loudness    mode
danceability    1.000000    0.061570    0.048222    -0.060654
energy          0.061570    1.000000    0.019930    0.042376
loudness        0.048222    0.019930    1.000000    -0.044294
mode           -0.060654    0.042376    -0.044294   1.000000

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Heatmap(
        x = df_corr.columns,
        y = df_corr.index,
        z = np.array(df_corr),
        text=df_corr.values,
        texttemplate='%{text:.2f}'
    )
)
fig.show()
```

[image]