# Percentage of Row Total in Heatmap Python

Tags: python, plotly, pivot, heatmap

I would like to show the numbers as percentage of Row (or Column) Total for this heatmap. I am using Plotly library for the plotting.
[image]

I could find a way to get the percentage of row total using code below. I would really appreciate any help to plot these percentages in a heatmap for better visualisation.

[image]

Comment: Does this solution answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72195177/correlation-matrix-in-plotly?

Comment: This is correlation between variables. What I would like to plot is the percentage of row total. So it does not help, thanks.

Comment: Ok, so you want to plot the heatmap for `pivotdf_unstack`, right?

Comment: yes, I would like to plot the numbers shown in pivotdf_unstack into a heatmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [px.imshow()](https://plotly.com/python/heatmaps/) to create a heatmap for your dataframe such that:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.imshow(pivotdf_unstack, text_auto=True, aspect="auto")
fig.show()
```

You can replace the null values with any suitable values you think.
You will get a heatmap with null values like:

[image]

Comment: Didn't know the solution was that simple! Thanks a lot. This totally works :)